# Delay in JointStates

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am working on ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04. I am simulating my robot with gazebo and ros-control however the terminal always shows this warning ::

```
process[coro/joint_controller_spawner-1]: started with pid [21948]

process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [21949] Loaded

joint_state_controller Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully

[coro/joint_controller_spawner-1] process has finished cleanly log file: /home/bhoot/.ros/log/54979f64-835c-11e8-8840-a08cfdeabd87/coro-joint_controller_spawner-1*.log

1531129330.670413 seconds old.

[ WARN] [1531129358.795952825]: Received JointState is 1531129333.605810 seconds old.

[ WARN] [1531129368.805861605]: Received JointState is 1531129336.583829 seconds old.

[ WARN] [1531129378.812465284]: Received JointState is 1531129339.550438 seconds old.

[ WARN] [1531129388.815334092]: Received JointState is 1531129342.521295 seconds old.
```

My yaml files and launch files are attached :

[C:\fakepath\Selection_034.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15311300812581273.png)

[C:\fakepath\Selection_035.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15311301698291515.png)

[C:\fakepath\Selection_036.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15311302044344638.png)

[C:\fakepath\Selection_037.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15311302361836977.png)

I tried changing the rate of jpint values publisher, but no use. Any idea what I am  missing ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296720/delay-in-jointstates/) by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2018-07-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-09**:
Please don't use images for text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste them. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the your files instead of using images.

**Comment by [athikr](https://answers.ros.org/users/37918/athikr/) on 2018-12-06**:
I am having the same issue, did you solve it.

**Comment by [Pulkit123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28301/pulkit123/) on 2018-12-06**:
Yeah I solved it, using use_sim_time=true in gazebo_world.launch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting use_sim_time=true, as it seems to be getting very old joint states

---

Originally posted by [Ridhwanluthra](https://answers.ros.org/users/34902/ridhwanluthra/) with karma: 66 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3